# Amazon S3 bucket file upload response is not available

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, multer, multer-s3, s3-bucket

I'm using **multer** ,**aws-sdk** and **multer-s3**  packages along with express.

when users edit profile user may change profile picture /avatar or not.

I've passed multer object

> multer({storage:
>   multer.memoryStorage()}).single('profileHeroImageEdit')

if a file with current request then I will upload the file  to s3 bucket but I am not getting any response from **upload_replace** where **req.file.location** will provide the url of S3 bucket (file's location).
And Inside **upload_replace**  I can get the file I am trying to upload(**req.file**) but I want the location of uploaded file to S3 bucket .

What I'm missing ? Help will be appreciated

```
router.put("/:id",multer({ storage: 
multer.memoryStorage()}).single('profileHeroImageEdit'), 
middleware.checkProfileOwnership,function(req, res){
    if(isFileExists(req)==false){
        delete req.body.profileHeroImage      

     }
     else{
         console.log('file has')
         var upload_replace = multer({
            limits:{
                fileSize:MAX_FILE_SIZE,
                files:1
            },
            storage: multerS3({
                s3: photoBucket,
                bucket: BucketName,
                acl: 'public-read',
                metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
                    cb(null, { fieldName: file.fieldname });
                },
                key: function (req, file, cb) {
                    cb(null,Date.now().toString())

                }
            })
        }).single('profileHeroImageEdit') 

        upload_replace(req, res, function (err,log) {
           console.log('request log')
            console.log(req.file.location)
           console.log()
        }); 


     }
    Profile.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.profile, function(err, updatedProfile){
        if (err){
            res.redirect("/profiles");
        } else {
            res.redirect("/profiles/" + req.params.id);
        }
    });
});

function isFileExists(request){
    if(request.file)
    {
        return true 
    }
    else{
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have whole code using multer and aws-sdk

1. include this files and npm install all

   ```
   //aws s3 packages
   const aws = require("aws-sdk");
   const multerS3 = require("multer-s3");
   const multer = require("multer");
   const path = require("path");
   ```
2. then

   ```
   //profile image upload start
   const s3 = new aws.S3({
     accessKeyId: "***",
     secretAccessKey: "***",
     Bucket: "***"
   });

   //Singe profile image upload

   const profileImgUpload = multer({
     storage: multerS3({
       s3: s3,
       bucket: "***",
       acl: "public-read",
       key: function(req, file, cb) {
         cb(
           null,
           path.basename(file.originalname, path.extname(file.originalname)) +
             "-" +
             Date.now() +
             path.extname(file.originalname)
         );
       }
     }),
     limits: { fileSize: 2000000 }, // In bytes: 2000000 bytes = 2 MB
     fileFilter: function(req, file, cb) {
       checkFileType(file, cb);
     }
   }).single("profileImage");

   // getExtension of file by this function
   function getExtension(filename) {
     var parts = filename.split(".");
     return parts[parts.length - 1];
   }

   //checkfile type of input function
   function checkFileType(file, cb) {
     const ext = getExtension(file.originalname);
     switch (ext.toLowerCase()) {
       case "jpeg":
       case "jpg":
       case "png":
       case "gif":
         return cb(null, true);
     }
     cb("Error: Images Only!");
   }

   router.post(
     "/image",
     passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }),
     (req, res) => {
       profileImgUpload(req, res, error => {
         if (error) {
           res.json({ error: error });
         } else {
           //here we can get req.body
           const userDp = {};

           //end of getting values

           // If File not found then dont store anything
           if (req.file !== undefined) userDp.dpUrl = req.file.location;
           // Save the file name into database into profile model

           User.findOne({ email: req.user.email }).then(user => {
             if (user) {
               // Update
               User.findOneAndUpdate(
                 { email: req.user.email },
                 { $set: userDp },
                 { new: true }
               ).then(user => res.json(user));
             } else {
               res.json({ msg: "not able not update data" });
             }
           });
         }
       });
     }
   );
   ```

3.need to send data from react frontend by using

```
const data = new Formdata();
data.append()
```

and by including headers also

Answer (score 0):

Add a listener for when the OutgoingMessage to upload the photo to S3 is completed. The `on-finished` library is handy for this.

```
const onFinished = require('on-finished');
const print = process._rawDebug;

uploadReplace(req, null, function (err) {
  onFinished(req, function () {
    if (err) print(err);
    print(req.file.location);
    // Other things can be done here
  })
});
```

Comment: but Problem is file was not uploaded to aws and the listener I've  attached  also says `undefined`  for `console.log (req.file.location)`

Comment: Are you seeing an error printed to the terminal? If so, can you share the error output?